# SQl Server, No module named 'revoscalepy.computecontext'

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, revoscalepy

I followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install-sql-2022?view=sql-server-ver16) to install Python and configure Python runtime with SQL Server. When I ran this script

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @script=N'import sys;print(sys.version)',@language=N'Python'
GO
```

this error popped up:

```
Msg 39012, Level 16, State 14, Line 0
Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'Python' script for request id: A38DC621-AD74-4408- 
856E-70CBAFDD699F. Please check the requirements of 'Python' runtime.
STDERR message(s) from external script: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'revoscalepy.computecontext'
```

But computercontext does exist in the revoscalepy folder, C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext. What causes the above error?

Comment: What's the output of `select @@version` for your SQL Server instance?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, the output is Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021522) - 16.0.1050 (X64) ...